# using ajax for highchart codeigniter, how?

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, highcharts

just need to give this `chart.series[0].update({ your data })}` to your ajax and `chart = new Highcharts.chart` on a highchart as an identifier... 
`chart.series [0] .update ()` to provide new data input, so if you want to display based on the selected data this might help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#kategori').change(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/kategori/get_grafik_tutor",
            method : "POST",
            data : {id: id},
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(data){
                chart.series[0].update({
                  name: "Data Hadir",
                  data: data.hasil
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and My Highchart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
               text: 'Grafik Absensi Tutor',
               x: -20
              },
              subtitle: {
               text: 'Data Kehadiran',
               x: -20
              },
              xAxis: {
               categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun',
                                'Jul', 'Ags', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Des']
              },
              yAxis: {
               title: {
                text: 'Total Absensi'
               }
              },
            plotOptions: {
                line: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
              }]
        });
```

I hope this can help your problem.

Comment: instead of `tutorgrafik(hasil);` try `tutorgrafik(data.hasil);` in your success function

Comment: First in you controller It should give error in `echo json_encode($hasil);`  as you have not defined `$hasil`, so  update controller with `echo json_encode( $data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ); `and also in success function call function as `tutorgrafik(data.hasil);`